# Supress duplicate error in aot compiler

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-template

I have a huge codebase written in Angular 2 that I want to build and optimize using angular-cli. **ng build** works fine. However , when I run **ng build --prod** I get one error  which has had me banging my head against the wall. It says that I have  a duplicate identifier. This error stops the whole dist folder from being  outputted. Yet I am 100% sure there is no duplicate identifier in my component. I cannot debug anything as the ng.factory file is never outputted. How should I tell the compiler thank you,..but I have no duplicates..I know what I am doing.

[image]

If I comment the template which links to this component **ng build --prod** works fine. In the template to this offending component I have markup like this

```
 <li class="listmathSubDomain" *ngFor="let subdomain of subjectVM.subDomainArray" [ngClass]="{'active': subdomain.Description == subjectVM.SelectedSubDomain}">
```

How does 'active' become a duplicate identifier then,  only in aot. Have I missed an important concept on  how aot compilation works.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this line was the culprit in AOT.

```
[ngClass]="{'active': math.Name == subjectVM.SelectedMathDomain,'active': math.Title == subjectVM.SelectedDomain}"
```

And I changed it to

```
[ngClass]="{'active': (math.Name == subjectVM.SelectedMathDomain || math.Title == subjectVM.SelectedDomain)}"
```

I wonder why the first line does not throw an error in JIT.

Comment: This is something weird but yes worked for me. Thanks @Abide. Thumbs up :)